# OpenLDAP as proxy to Active Directory does not bind with bindDN from slapd.conf

Tags: active-directory, proxy, ldap, centos7, openldap

Background info:

CentOS 7  3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64

This server will be used as a proxy to Active Directory.

Currently it seems as if `ldapsearch` does not care about /etc/openldap/slapd.conf and will not bind unless I pass the bindDN and password directly using -D and -w.

I did a fresh install of OpenLDAP-servers

Edited slapd.conf with the following:

```
### Schema includes ###########################################################
include                 /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include                 /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include                 /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include                 /etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema
include                 /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema

## Module paths ##############################################################
modulepath              /usr/lib64/openldap/
moduleload              back_ldap
moduleload              rwm

## Support both LDAPv2 and LDAPv3
allow           bind_v2

# Main settings ###############################################################
pidfile                 /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile                /var/run/openldap/slapd.args

### Database definition (Proxy to AD) #########################################
database                ldap
readonly                yes
protocol-version        3
rebind-as-user          yes
uri                     "ldap://10.0.0.90:389"
suffix                  "DC=secretdomain,DC=com"
idassert-bind           bindmethod=simple
                        binddn="CN=MropenLDAP,OU=Administration,DC=secretdomain,DC=com"
                        credentials=topsecretpass
                        mode=none
idassert-authzFrom      "*"
overlay                 rwm
rwm-map                 attribute       uid     sAMAccountName
rwm-map                 attribute       mail    proxyAddresses

### Logging ###################################################################
logfile                 /var/log/slapd/slapd.log
loglevel                1
```

Ran: `slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/`

Made sure ownership and permissions are correct then restarted slapd.

The following does not work:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://10.0.0.90 -x -b "OU=Administration,DC=secretdomain,DC=com" -v -LLL "(samaccountname=someusername)"

ldapsearch -H ldap://10.0.0.90 -x -b "OU=Administration,DC=secretdomain,DC=com" -v -LLL
```

It gives me this error:

```
ldap_initialize( ldap://10.0.0.90:389/??base )
filter: (objectclass=*)
requesting: All userApplication attributes
Operations error (1)
Additional information: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1
```

However, when I pass the bind account DN directly it works . I checked that both of these pieces of information are identical from the /etc/openldap/slapd.conf file:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://10.0.0.90 -x -b "OU=Administration,DC=secretdomain,DC=com" -v -LLL -D "CN=MropenLDAP,OU=Administration,DC=secretdomain,DC=com" "(samaccountname=someusername)" -w topsecretpass
```

Comment: If you don't wish to pass bindDn and password try using meta as the backend instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58432331/configuring-ldap-proxy-server-with-multiple-ad-ldap-servers for more details. Currently, you are using ldap as the backend. This is the official documentation for meta backend https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/slapd-meta.5.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ldapsearch` doesn't use `slapd.conf` it uses `ldap.conf` (or a number of other places as outlined below). `Binddn` cannot usefully be set in the global ldap.conf file as it's considered a user-only option an thus ignored if found there.

---

> [LDAP.CONF(5)](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=ldap.conf)
>
> NAME
>          ldap.conf, .ldaprc - LDAP configuration file/environment variables
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          /etc/openldap/ldap.conf, ldaprc, .ldaprc, $LDAP
>
> DESCRIPTION
>   If the environment variable LDAPNOINIT is defined, all defaulting is disabled.
>
> The ldap.conf configuration file is used to set system-wide defaults to be applied when running ldap clients.
>
> Users may create an optional configuration file, ldaprc or .ldaprc, in their home directory which will be used to override the system-wide defaults file.  The file ldaprc in the current working directory is also used.
>
> Additional  configuration  files  can  be specified using the LDAPCONF and LDAPRC environment variables.  LDAPCONF may be set to the path of a configuration file.  This path can be absolute or relative to the current working directory.  The LDAPRC, if defined, should be the basename of a file in the current working directory or in the user's home directory.
>
> Environmental variables may also be used to augment the file based defaults.  The name of the variable is the option name with an added prefix of LDAP.  For example, to define BASE via the environment, set the variable LDAPBASE to the desired value.
>
> Some options are user-only.  Such options are ignored if present in the ldap.conf (or file specified by LDAPCONF).
>
> Thus the following files and variables are read, in order:
>              variable     $LDAPNOINIT, and if that is not set:
>              system file  /etc/openldap/ldap.conf,
>              user files   $HOME/ldaprc,  $HOME/.ldaprc,  ./ldaprc,
>              system file  $LDAPCONF,
>              user files   $HOME/$LDAPRC, $HOME/.$LDAPRC, ./$LDAPRC,
>              variables    $LDAP.
>          Settings late in the list override earlier ones.
>
> `BINDDN <dn>`
>         Specifies the default bind DN to use when performing ldap operations.  The bind DN must be specified as a Distinguished Name in LDAP format.  `This is a user-only option.`

Comment: I tried putting the bindDN config in ldap.conf but it is still not using that DN to bind.
I followed something similar to this: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28963888/OpenLDAP-Proxy-to-Active-Directy.html[link]

Comment: I followed this config: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/OpenLDAP_as_proxy_to_AD and it works now, I also added a few things in the ldap.conf file and it read it right away. Thanks!