# OpenLDAP: Non-anonymous access for PAM/NSS

Tags: ldap, pam, nss

I've install LDAP with PAM/NSS. So I've installed libnss-ldap libpam-ldap nscd on my Debian 9

`apt-get install libnss-ldap libpam-ldap nscd`

I configured it and all was working rigth. I decided to disable anonymous access. I used this ldif:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcDisallows
olcDisallows: bind_anon
```

Now i can't access to the users in the LDAP. Logs:

```sh
su iron
cat /var/log/auth.log
```

```
May  7 06:39:52 DebianMM nscd: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://my-server.local: Inappropriate authentication
May  7 06:39:52 DebianMM nscd: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server...
May  7 06:39:52 DebianMM nscd: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://my-server.local: Inappropriate authentication
May  7 06:39:52 DebianMM nscd: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server (sleeping 1 seconds)...
May  7 06:39:53 DebianMM nscd: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://my-server.local: Inappropriate authentication
May  7 06:39:53 DebianMM nscd: nss_ldap: could not search LDAP server - Server is unavailable
May  7 06:39:53 DebianMM su[702]: No passwd entry for user 'iron'
May  7 06:39:53 DebianMM su[702]: FAILED su for iron by root
May  7 06:39:53 DebianMM su[702]: - /dev/pts/0 root:iron
```

This is my /etc/ldap/ldap.conf:

```
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

BASE    dc=my-server,dc=local
URI     ldap://my-server.local:389

#SIZELIMIT      12
#TIMELIMIT      15
#DEREF          never

# TLS certificates (needed for GnuTLS)
TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
binddn cn=admin,dc=my-server,dc=local
bindpw password_clear
```

I need the login work again
Thank you

Comment: May be you should check if the binddn/bindpw you are using is correct.

Comment: I was wrong. Have a look here: https://serverfault.com/questions/805441/openldap-as-proxy-to-active-directory-does-not-bind-with-binddn-from-slapd-conf. May be you need to add the binddn/password in nlscd.conf or pam_ldap.con.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding binddn in ldap.conf doesn't work. Please ignore my previous answer.

You can try adding binddn in the following files:

```
/etc/libnss-ldap.conf

/etc/pam_ldap.conf
```

And password here:

```
/etc/ldap.secret
```

Comment: I already tried that, but is not working

Comment: @manulqwerty, it is all not very clear from your question. Then you should update your question.

Comment: Ok, i added my /etc/ldap/ldap.conf , maybe theres a problem in it? Can I use the admin account, or i need to create another ?

Comment: Have you tried it? Because it is not working for me

Comment: @manulqwerty, are you still having problem?

Comment: I fixed it reinstalling everything